# Learn Windows Assembly on Linux

Tags: assembly

I'm on Kali linux 64bit, and i want to learn windows assebly language x86, is this possible, and if it is, how can i do it?

Comment: You could run [dosbox](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5634) through [wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: and i can can practice windows assembly on my 64bits kali linux laptop ?

Comment: Actually I don't think it will do what you are after.

Comment: so, please how do you propose i learn assembly lanuage
I have AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2
with Kali Linux OS 64-bits

Comment: I have no idea how you could set it up like you were programming for a windows platform besides maybe running copy of windows in a virtual machine, but why not just learn 32 bit or 64 bit assembly for linux, both will work with a 64 bit platform, look for a good book or some decent tutorials, that should get you started, just look for "assembly with linux" for `x86` or `x64` materials (i.e "hello world" using `nasm` and `ld` for `x86 linux`), other than that I don't know how to help, what was best for me might not be best for you, good luck.

Comment: alright, sounds good enough. thanks, a lot... So i'll just start with 32bit assembly then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from system calls (and perhaps program header), which of course are going to be different, assembly on x86/Linux is the same as assembly on x86/Windows.

First, you are going to need an assembler. I'd suggest [fasm](http://www.flatassembler.net) or [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) for this. Both are very good and come with documentation that will help you get started.

Edit: To make this a little more clear, the assembly *syntax* is determined by the assembler you use – see the above links for more information. Once you have written a working assembly program, you can go on to call windows function, as this [pdf tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww-s.acm.illinois.edu%2Fsigwin%2Fold%2Fworkshops%2Fwinasmtut.pdf) explains. Apart from the function call code, which is different between Linux and Windows, the code is exactly the same for both systems.

Comment: I'd suggest first learning the assembly basics. It'll be easier to call windows functions afterwards.

Comment: Let me explain my situation sir... I have a 64-bits laptop with AMD processor with kali linux OS. So what i'm asking is is it possible to learn windows assembly such as its x86 and x64 assembly language on my laptop ?

Comment: hmph, okay, great! thanks a lot,  i tried opening the pdf link, but it wasn't showing anything related to assembly ?